# How to create KStream with a static list of records for unit testing purpose

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to write unit tests for a class which's using Kafka streams, like this:

```
KStream stream = streamBuilder.stream(topic)
stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
    // do some data manipulations and validations
});
```

Is there some way to add unit tests for this by creating a KStream from static data, like this to get a stream of Strings :

```
arrayList.stream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the[ToplogyTestDriver](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TopologyTestDriver.html) and the [TestInputTopic](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestInputTopic.html) allows you to add static records to test a topology with methods like [TestInputTopic.pipeKeyValueList](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TestInputTopic.html#pipeKeyValueList-java.util.List-).  Testing in this manner allows you to validate your topology without the overhead of running a physical broker.

You can look at the [testing Kafka Streams docs](https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html) for more information.

HTH,
Bill